# Virtual Machine does not recognize source media to boot. Need help!

Tags: virtualization

I just installed the Oracle VM to create a virtual image of Windows XP because I had issues running Yahoo Messenger with Wine. So I decided to try the virtualization instead, but as soon as I installed the virtual machine for XP and started it, for some reason it does not recognize the boot media to start the virtual system installation process.
I need help, I really love my Ubuntu OS and I don't want to go back to windows, but unfortunately I need to install at least a couple of windows programs that with Ubuntu I haven't able to run the way they should work.

Comment: When you say it does not recognize the boot media, what exactly are using? An actual Windows XP CD, or and ISO image?

Answer (score 0):

If you're not heavily invested in Oracle VM, you should check out [Virtual Box OSE](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VirtualBox), which should be available in the package manager. I use it for running Windows programs, and for testing different versions of Internet Explorer.

It's GUI prompts for an ISO or physical disc for installation when you first start a new VM, but, if you're missing that for some reason, you can go to Devices > CD/DVD Devices > More CD/DVD Images... within a virtual machine window to open VB's Virtual Media Manager, then click the Add button to add a new CD/DVD image. Physical discs should be shown at Devices > CD/DVD Devices > (the disk name)

Answer (score 0):

To boot Virtual Box with an installation medium we have two options. We can either mount a **bootable** CD .iso image as a virtual CD drive, or we use the host CD/DVD-drive for booting from a real installation CD. After having set up the basics of a machine such as architecture, prozessor, memory, etc. we go to the *Storage* settings int the Virtual Box Manager and choose the CD in the *IDE Controller -> CD/DVD Drive*:

[image]

Use the dropdown menu from the CD icon on the right side to add a virtual CD/DVD disk file (which is the bootable .iso CD image mentioned above) or choose the *Host Drive*  in case you have an installation CD only.

In case you already have a virtual hard drive with another bootable OS you may want to change the boot priority in *System -> Motherboard* settings first:

[image]

After restarting the machine it will boot the installation medium very much like a real computer does.

Comment: Wow, it really helped me out. Thanks a lot! You saved my life and kept me from going back to Windows, I really appreciate your help.